# Write a Unit Test For a StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing

I have a bug that occurs in a low-level system under rare circumstances which results in a `StackOverflowException`. I've written a test that reproduces the bug, but the test can never run to completion, failure or success, due to the nature of a stack overflow. Test was run using `mstest` and `NUnit`.

What can I do to write a test for this scenario, which fails rather than terminates when the stack is busted?

Comment: Presumably once you've fixed the bug, it will just pass. I'd be tempted to do that... the failure mode would only matter if the bug were reintroduced, and don't forget that any *other* breakage resulting in a stack overflow will crash the process too, so it's not like this would be that different.

Comment: Unit Testing is for testing features...  An expected ValidationException could be such a feature, but StackOverflow or OutOfMemory can not be. This is not what the frameworks are for. So you can only test the absence of such a failure, and have your Build crash otherwise. Which sounds like something I could live with.

Comment: MS went out of its *way* to ensure managed code can't recover from a SOE, even if it took the extreme care and attention necessary to do it without somehow making things even worse (which is a big if, and the main reason they went out of their way). Rather than testing for the presence or absence of an exception directly, you might go more roundabout and identify the structure or pattern that caused the failure to creep in, and find a way to test for the reintroduction of that (or better yet, make it impossible). You would be writing a regression test this way, though, not a unit test proper.

Comment: The thread running the test will probably terminate.  Can you setup a handler for `Application.ThreadException` or `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` to verify a `StackOverflowException` occurred?  You might need to set  `Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode` to `CatchException`, too.

Comment: I guess my thinking was that this test was to ensure the system operated correctly when configured and used in a particular way. It is, in essence, testing a feature of the system, and any exception occurring in the test would be failure. Regardless, it seems the path of least resistance is to simply fix the bug and watch the test pass, which is the route I'll take.